# In the energy released by fission of uranium nucleus, why don't we take into account the factor *2* for binding energy of the *two* final states?

Tags: nuclear-physics

In the $^{235}U$, the binding energy per nucleon is around $7.6\ MeV$.
Once it has followed a fission, it splits in two objects, where each one has a typical binding energy per nucleon of around $8.4\ MeV$.

The resulting energy released is stated to be around 0.8 or 0.9 MeV per nucleon : $8.4 - 7.6\ MeV$.

My question is : why don't we take into account the fact that there are two final objects, thus, why don't we compute the released energy as $8.4 \times 2 - 7.6$ ?

Comment: There are 4-6 final objects: two nuclei, and 2-4 neutrons. Sometimes there is 3 nuclei.  All the binding energies plus kinetic energies are added together and substituted from the binding energies, plus kinetic energies of the original bodies (which is typically 1 neutron and 1 uranium nucleus).

Comment: Overall, about the same total numbers of nucleons come out. Not twice as many. (And certainly not counting the few free neutrons released as nucleons).

Comment: Nice comments, but those both seem like answers not comments. Please write them up!

Comment: thank you : indeed the keypoint is that the number of nucleon is conserved